# Access the method / filter Django's admin app uses to present table field names

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

Example model:

```
class People(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

If I add this to admin.py, I get the field titles as "First name" and "Last name".  I assume there must be access to the method or template filter that does this (i.e "last_name" -> "Last name"), but I can't seem to find it.  I know I can add a method in the model, create a template tag or do the logic in a view.  I want to know explicitly if I can access the same feature that the admin system does.

Answer (score 0):

It happens in various places when constructing the template variable `app_list` in:

- `django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite.index`
- `django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite.app_index`

It calls `.title()` on the name of Django apps which causes the first character to be capitalized.

It appears the latest developemnt version of Django doesn't provide a way to customize that (at the time of writing). That means your options are to override multiple admin templates or to hack your way around it by subclassing Django's admin classes.